# store value of column into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to get a value of column, and put it into variable of the same type of that column, as the following :

```
select FRI_SEC_TEMP into friday_seconds
from TEMPTABLE 
where rownum<2;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(friday_seconds);
```

but when I run the script, it give me the following error:

> > Query Run In:Query Result 6

```
Error starting at line : 61 in command -
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(friday_seconds)
Error report -
Unknown Command
```

and when I run just the select statement I get the following error:

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: do you execute it as a pl sql block? - just surround your script from the question with `begin - end;`

Comment: @Evgeni thanks! that's work :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute the script as a PL SQL block by  surrounding it with `begin - end`

```
begin
  select FRI_SEC_TEMP into friday_seconds
    from TEMPTABLE 
   where rownum<2;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(friday_seconds); 
end;
```